Calculating significant difference between several averages of the same samples
I currently have a dataset consisting of 8 measurements taken around a cylindrical core sample at intervals of 90 degrees to each other, 2 measurements per point (observing the core face on these would be equivalent to a clock face of 12, 3, 6 & 9).
As these measurements take a long time to measure, i want to know if there is any significant statistical difference between:

The average of each point measurement, i.e the 2 measurements at each point.
The average of points taken at at 12 & 6 and 3 & 9 (such as these represent differences in vertical and horizontal measurements)
&
The average of all measurements together.

Essentially i want to compare the averages of all these determine if there is any major difference between them. Currently i am contemplating: Plotting and looking for outliers, t test and excel conditional formatting.
Is there any particular test i should be looking at implementing?
An examples of a dataset would be:



orientation
K




First
184.6


Second
189.6


First
285.5


Second
262.6


First
051.9


Second
071.7


First
359.0


Second
393.9



